# Is there a way once the img src tag is replaced with new src the call does not go to old src at all

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace src attribute of img tag using jquery to render an image.

The reason I have to do this is because I don't have control on page where img tag is present.

I can only use jquery to replace the src.
However, the call still goes to old src before rendering the image specified by new src.

This is what I tried:

```
jq('img[src="' + ImgSrc + '"]').hide(0).attr('src', buttonUrlNew).show(0);
```

where `ImgSrc` is the old src and `buttonUrlNew` is the new src.
using hide I am able to hide the image of old src, however, in Network calls I can see the call is being made any how to old src. Is there a way I can stop this call from being made at all?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you can update the src property and the browser will fetch the new image automatically. I think you're better off duplicating the img element outside of the DOM, changing the src, then replacing the old img element with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a caching issue, try this one:

```
jq('img[src="' + ImgSrc + '"]').hide(0).attr('src', buttonUrlNew + "?v=" + new Date().getTime()).show(0);
```

There is no need to Hide and Show images, you can directly achieve without doing  it.

```
jq('img[src="' + ImgSrc + '"]').attr('src', buttonUrlNew + "?v=" + new Date().getTime());
```

It will prevent to get image from catch and forced to download a new image.

Comment: Tried this without using hide or show.Still it shows the old src image for few seconds before showing the new src image.I used hide and show to hide the old src and show the new one which works. However, what I want is call not to do at all to the old src which I can see in Network tab.

Comment: It' happens because the browser is loading those image from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get why you use hide and show on that image. I was able to just set the src attribute and the image was updated immediately. I used an svg as the first and the second image but that should not make the result any different.
In addition, I would use an ID as the selector since it'll eliminate any wrong format in the URL of the first image (absolute/relative and so on). 
Like so: `$('#image').attr('src', buttonUrlNew);`